# Pass in a slot with a reference value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my component I have this scoped slot:

```
<slot name="test">
    <input ref="inputTest">
</slot>
```

In the parent I do this:

```
<div slot="test">
    <input ref="inputTest">
</div>
```

But when I tried to access the ref later in my component:

```
console.log(this.$refs.inputTest);
```

I get undefined.

How can I pass in a slot that has a reference?

Comment: Which component are you trying to use the ref in? The parent or the child?

Comment: The child component.

Comment: I think OP wants to get ref in child component. Interesting problem though, I'm not sure if slots are dynamic enough to let you do something like that, slots don't even have events

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? As you found out, the ref is only going to be available in the parent. You could additionally pass the ref in as a prop (I imagine), but then it seems like you'd just be better off taking a different approach.

Comment: Actually, `$refs` is not reactive, so it'd be even more work.

Comment: Could you please tell me what behavior you try to achieve? I think there might be a better way for this (without `ref`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `refs` from parent component to child component.

You can use [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) to pass the data between them.

```
<!-- pass ref as props -->
<slot name="test" :ref="inputTest">
    <input ref="inputTest">
</slot>


<!-- receive ref props -->
<template slot-scope="ref">
    <!-- bind ref to $refs -->
    <input ref="ref">
</div>
```

It will be confusing obviously. Thus, I would recommend to use any other suitable name for the props instead of ref.